# In series solution what form of the series should be assumed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-equations

As reading Quantum Mechanics I encountered some differential equations which can be solved by **series solution method**. In case of *Harmonic Oscillator* we assume the series as "$u(y)=\sum_{n}c_{n}y^{n}$".
On the other hand we assume the series solution for radial equation for hydrogen atom as "$u(y)=y^{p}\sum_{n}c_{n}y^{n}$ (p=const)".
My question is how(or why) to assume the series as $\sum_{n}c_{n}y^{n}$ or $y^{p}\sum_{n}c_{n}y^{n}$ (p=const) for a differential equation?
I'm reading **Principles of Quantum Mechanics** by **R. Shankar**.

Answer (score 2):

We divide the linear second order ordinary differential equations into 3 categories:
regular, regular singular and essential singular.

For a standard 2nd order homogeneous linear ODE
$$\tag{1}
   \ddot y + p(x) \dot y + q(x) y = 0.
$$

1. At a point $x = x_0$, Eq.(1) is call regular if both p(x) and q(x) are analytical at $x_0$, then $x_0$ is a regular point of the ODE.
2. It is a singular point, if either $p(x_0)$ or $q(x_0)$ is not analytical.

2(a). For a singular pointt, if both $(x- x_0) p(x)$ and $(x-x_0)^2 q(x)$ are analytical at $x_0$, then $x_0$ is a regular singular point.

2(b). Otherwise, it is a essential sigular point.

The rules:

1. Expanding $y(x)$ at a regular point will be the taylor series:

$$
  y(x) = \sum_0 a_n x^n.
$$

2. There is at least a series solution at a regular singular point. Expanding $y(x)$ at a regular singular point has to employ Frobenius method:
   $$
     y(x) = x^r \sum_0 a_n x^n.
   $$
3. There is no series solution at a essential sigular point, i.e. $y(x) = \ln (x-x_0) $.

Comment: I think 2nd equation from bottom should be $y(x)=x^{r}\sum_{n}a_{n}x^{n}$ . Also all sums should be from 0 to ∞. However, are you saying that if there is a singular point then we assume the solution as $y(x)=x^{r}\sum_{n}a_{n}x^{n}$ this? Is that Frobenius theorem?

Comment: Yes. If it is regular singular, not essential singular, then you may try the Fobenius form

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back and start with the differential equation for
the radial wave function $U_{E\ell}(r)$ for a particle in a central field $V(r)$,
like for example the hydrogen atom where we have $V(r)\propto\frac{1}{r}$.
Quoted from Shankar's "Principles of Quantum Mechanics", equation 12.6.5:
$$\left\{\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{2\mu}{\hbar^2}\left[
E-V(r)-\frac{\ell(\ell+1)\hbar^2}{2\mu r^2}
\right]\right\}U_{E\ell}(r)=0 \tag{1}$$
where $E$ is the total energy, $V(r)$ is the potential energy,
and $\ell$ is the angular momentum quantum number.

Finding solutions for this differential equation is not easy.
So let's first consider only the behavior for very small and very large $r$.

For very small $r$ in equation (1) the $\frac{1}{r^2}$ term dominates over the
$E$ and $V(r)$ terms. So we can approximate
$$\left\{\frac{d^2}{dr^2}-\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2}\right\}U_{E\ell}(r) \approx 0 \quad\text{, for small $r$} \tag{2}$$
which has the obvious solution
$$U_{E\ell}(r)\approx r^{\ell+1} \quad\text{, for small $r$}.\tag{3}$$

For very large $r$ in equation (1) the $E$ term dominates over the
$V(r)$ and $\frac{1}{r^2}$ terms. So we can approximate
$$\left\{\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{2\mu E}{\hbar^2}\right\}U_{E\ell}(r) \approx 0  \quad\text{, for large $r$}\tag{4}$$
which has the obvious solution
$$U_{E\ell}(r)\approx e^{-\sqrt{2\mu E/\hbar^2}r} \quad\text{, for large $r$}.\tag{5}$$

Inspired by the approximate solutions (3) and (5) we choose the following approach
for the entire range of $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$:
$$U_{E\ell}(r) = r^{\ell+1} A_{E\ell}(r)e^{-\sqrt{2\mu E/\hbar^2}r} \tag{6}$$
The function $A_{E\ell}(r)$ needs to behave well
for small and large $r$, or else the good behavior of the solution $U_{E\ell}(r)$
would be spoiled.
So we choose a power series approach
$$A_{E\ell}(r) = \sum_{\nu=0}^\infty c_\nu r^\nu.\tag{7}$$
We want this function to behave well at $r=0$.
Therefore we start the series with $\nu=0$, and avoid any terms with negative $\nu$.
So we have
$$A_{E\ell}(r)\approx c_0 \quad\text{, for small $r$}$$
which is just fine.

We also want this function not to grow too much at $r\to\infty$,
This will require the series to terminate at some $\nu$,
but this is another big topic which I will skip here.